# Parametric formula for the shape of two circles connected with their outer tangents

Tags: circles, parametric, tangent-line

Suppose I have two circles that do not intersect.

$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=r_1$

$(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2=r_2$

If I know the two outer common tangent line segments:

$a_1y+b_1x=c_1$ for $x_{t_{11}}<x<x_{t_{21}}$ and $y_{t_{11}}<y<y_{t_{21}}$

$a_2y+b_2x=c_2$ for $x_{t_{12}}<x<x_{t_{22}}$ and $y_{t_{12}}<y<y_{t_{22}}$

where the $x_ts$ and $y_ts$ are the tangent points. What would be the parametric formula for the shape of the two circles connected with their outer tangent lines? An example is shown in below figure.

[image]

Comment: I expect that you’ll have to resort to a piecewise function here.

Comment: @amd, can you please give an example or a complete answer based on piecewise function?